# Is there any difference between transactions in asp.net and stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, transactions

If I have 3 sql queries and all three must be executed or none. Is there any difference if I write this query in asp.net code or stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing everything for current connection on one DB instance basically you will see no difference to use T-SQL transactions (BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT TRAN) or ADO.NET transactions(TransactionScope, BeginTransaction...)

But note that you can group multiple connections (requests to several DB instances) in one transaction using transaction scope.

Comment: There may well be performance issues if you keep the default isolation level of the TransactionScope - hence my answer...

Comment: I am not sure is there any difference performance wise, but I do believe that even if there is any difference it would be so miserable that you will not notice it. Just pay attention to isolation level.

Answer (score 2):

Both are valid ways for managine transactions. Using a stored procedure has the advantage of less network traffic, probably faster execution, better encapsulation of the database stuff etc, while using asp.net allows you to involve some high-level logic or using parts of your other programming which may influence what your queries do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TransctionScope` in .NET in the same way as you would use a transaction in the database.

Be careful to choose the right [isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) though.

By default, `TransactionScope` executes with the Serializable isolation level. This is probably not what you want.

The database default isolation level will more likely be Read committed.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency reasons you'd better write a SP with a transaction that rolls back on error. If only for simplicity, direct SQL, and the fact that SP get kind of compiled once, for faster execution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When using `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()` there is no difference.

This question, though, is a possible duplicate of [What's the difference between an SQL transaction at the stored procedure level and one at the SqlConnection level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046061/whats-the-difference-between-an-sql-transaction-at-the-stored-procedure-level-an)